# JaxB binding XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, binding, jaxb

JaxB when binding an improper date format to XMLGregorianCalendar is not throwing exception. Instead it assigns null. What could be the problem?

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "travelEndDate", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar travelEndDate;

<xs:complexType name="SearchCriteria">
<xs:attribute name="travelStartDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
<xs:attribute name="travelEndDate" type="xs:date" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB 2.X ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

This behaviour will vary a little between JAXB implementations.  MOXy for example will throw the following exception if the value is incorrect:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-3003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: Incorrect date format: [2011-02-50] (expected [YYYY-MM-DD])]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:225)
    at forum254.Demo.main(Demo.java:18)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-3003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: Incorrect date format: [2011-02-50] (expected [YYYY-MM-DD])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException.incorrectDateFormat(ConversionException.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLConversionManager.convertStringToXMLGregorianCalendar(XMLConversionManager.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLConversionManager.convertObjectToXMLGregorianCalendar(XMLConversionManager.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLConversionManager.convertObject(XMLConversionManager.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLField.convertValueBasedOnSchemaType(XMLField.java:712)
```

**Workaround**

To get an error reported on any JAXB implementation you can set an XML schema on the unmarshaller to perform validation:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html

Or you can implement an `XmlAdapter` to control the conversion (and throw an exception if necessary) yourself:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link is helpful for you:

http://eskatos.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/jaxb-custom-binding-for-joda-time/

It describes the handling of Dates in XML with custom Java Datatypes (here: JodaTime)

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will catch the exception:

```
try {
   String date = "your date here"
   XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException ex) {
       //DO STUFF
      }
```

Update:

After your addition of code, I am not sure how you will catch this. For that, I think you will need to do a null check and do what ever you want to.